# make op in prolog with operator definition theres have 'likes' and 'and'

Tags: prolog, operator-keyword, definition

I have knowladge base for information:

```
:- op(650,xfx,like).
john like cat.
john like dog.
john like bird.

mary like dog.
mary like horse.
mary like bird.
```

and i need predicate, when i write code like this:

```
?- Who like dog and bird.
```

So, will return this:

```
Who = john;
Who = mary.
```

I make one predicate like this:

```
:- op(700,xfx,and).
X and Y:- X,Y.
```

But with that code i just can write the code like this, if i want Who=john; Who=mary can show:

```
?-Who like dog and Who like bird.
```

Comment: Of interest: [write_canonical/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=write_canonical/1) Write Term on the current output stream using standard parenthesised prefix notation. e.g. `?- write_canonical(john like cat).
like(john,cat)
true.` or `?- write_canonical(Who like dog and bird).
like(_,and(dog,bird))
true.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Who like dog and bird` is going to be interpreted as:

```
(Who like dog) and bird
```

Which will generate an error because Prolog tries to query `bird` which has no facts or rules associated with it.

```
| ?- Who like dog and bird.
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,bird/0),(and)/2)
```

If you make `and` higher precedence than `like`, then this will be read as `Who like (dog and bird)` which will still fails, but will be a little closer:

```
:- op(600, xfx, and).

| ?- Who like dog and bird.

no
```

This fails because there's nothing in your facts or predicates that handles a compound direct object (there's no match for `... like (A and B)`. What you now need is a predicate to handle the compound term:

```
X like (A and B) :-
    X like A,
    X like B.
```

Then you'll get:

```
| ?- Who like dog and bird.

Who = john ? ;

Who = mary ? ;

no
| ?-
```

The whole solution looks like:

```
:- op(650, xfx, like).
:- op(600, xfx, and).

john like cat.
john like dog.
john like bird.

mary like dog.
mary like horse.
mary like bird.

X like (A and B) :-
    X like A,
    X like B.

X and Y :- X, Y.
```